# How to Implement Grep into CGI script Please?

Tags: html, c, cgi

I am having difficulty figuring out how to implement grep into my CGI script.  Basically I will receive a value of eg. 1500 from a HTML page.  The CGI script then runs and compares 1500 to a text file.  When it finds 1500 it prints the entire line and displays it on the webpage.  I would like some tips and pointers on how to do this please.  I understand that this involves grep but I don't really know how to put it in.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
char *data;
long m,n;
printf("%s%c%c\n",
"Content-Type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1",13,10);
printf("<TITLE>Webpage of Results</TITLE>\n");
printf("<H1>Temperatures</H1>\n");
data = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
```

The HTML passes the variable time=1500.  I understand (correct me if I am wrong) that QUERY_STRING will contain 1500?

Comment: Does your CGI script have to be in C? Something like this would be much simpler in another language, e.g. Perl.

Comment: Unfortunately it does, yeah I understand this would be so much easier in perl as I have seen loads of examples of this.

Answer (score 0):

For a URL of the form `whatever?query-string`, the enviroment variable `QUERY_STRING` contains the full `query-string` - in you case `time=1500` or similar.

You need to remember that there may be more then one field/value getting passed, seperated by `&`. By using [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) you can retrieve the parts of the query string one by one, [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) lets you compare them to other strings.

If you found the right token, you need to work with a file:

- [`fopen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) is used for opening a file
- [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) is used to retrieve a line
- use [`strstr()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr) to check if  a line contains a certain substring
- use [`fclose()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fclose) to close the file when you're done

Comment: Hi gf, thanks for the reply, well I know I won't have any other variables (for now) as I exclusively designed the HTML form like that.  Need to get one variable working first before adding more heh.  From what you're saying, I shouldn't need to use grep at all?

Comment: Never trust anything to send you exactly what you want :) With `grep` do you mean invoking an external process? I would recommend doing this yourself in C - invoking grep and retrieving its output isn't really easier.

Comment: Well...I'd like to hope it sends me what I want haha.  Well basically I'll explain what I'd like to do:

When receive TIME (1500)
Open Text File and Find string(1500)
Print string to HTML.

Really it's that simple but I don't know how to do it >< hence why I'd like a few pointers.

Comment: @Joey: Updated with the basic outline, that should get you going (and reading).

Answer (score 0):

some very straightforward analog of the grep in C is `strstr()` function

Comment: I've had a quick browse on strstr().  From what I understand, it is used in PHP?